# ionic2 phone call function show error: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

**about.html** here is html page

```
<ion-content>    
    <ion-fab center buttom>
      <button ion-fab color="light">
        <ion-icon name='call'></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-fab>

    <!-- <a ion-button color="light" href="tel:1800889958">
    立即拨打
    </a>   -->  

</ion-content>
```

**about.ts**

here is typescript page. I install call number plugin ald, **and import to app.module.ts also.**

error showing at 'this'

error message: unexpected token. A constructor, method , accessor, or property was expected.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})

export class AboutPage {

  constructor(private call: CallNumber) { }

  this.callNumber.callNumber("1800889958", true)
  .then(() => console.log('Launched dialer!'))
  .catch(() => console.log('Error launching dialer'));

}
```

CLI error show:

```
[09:56:04]  typescript: src/pages/about/about.ts, line: 14 
            Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected. 

      L14:    this.callNumber.callNumber("1800889958", true)
      L15:    .then(() => console.log('Launched dialer!'))

[09:56:04]  typescript: src/pages/about/about.ts, line: 18 
            Declaration or statement expected.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add `CallNumber` as a provider.

```
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number';

...

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    CallNumber
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And your `about.ts` should look something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})

export class AboutPage {

  constructor(private call: CallNumber, private platform: Platform) { 
     this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.callToNumber();
     });
  }

  private callToNumber() {
     this.call.callNumber("1800889958", true)
         .then(() => console.log('Launched dialer!'))
         .catch(() => console.log('Error launching dialer'));  
  }  

}
```

Check this line `this.call.callNumber`, you had `this.callNumber.callNumber` and that seems to be the issue.

Update:

Always wait to `Platform.ready()` promise when you want to use native functionallities, because if you try to do something with native apis before it will fail.

Comment: I add CallNumber in app.module.ts ald... but still show this error

Comment: After I try still got same problem

Comment: Check it now, I just noticed that the code was outside of the `constructor`

Comment: Thanks a lot, error solved ald.. 
But one more problem is call function not working

Comment: that is because you need to wait for `platform.ready` promise, I'll update the code, remember to mark the answer as the solution.